# Track files transferred from unauthorized user on private WiFi

Tags: macos, wifi, command-line, hacking, apple-silicon

I was hacked yesterday and from what I see, it looks like it was someone who lives with me and shares WiFi.

Is there a way to find on Mac where my files were sent to and the device id, type, or something that helps to narrow down the exploiter?

Edit 1.

The user and I were added to the same Family Group in Apple.
I used some of his apps memberships on my computer, Setapp, Spotify and Adobe.

I used this so far:

% history | grep "defaults write" >> ~/Documents/defaultsLog.txt

Found this on the reports:

````
Mon Jan 18 15:16:20.424 Usb Host Notification Error Apple80211Set: Device power is off seqNum 2527 en0
Mon Jan 18 15:16:20.588 <airport[399]> systemWokenByWiFi: System Wake Reason not found
Mon Jan 18 15:16:20.642 <kernel>  IOCTL (from pid 399) not recognized: 5 out of 379
Mon Jan 18 15:16:20.899 Usb Host Notification en0 driver available, seqNum 2528, Total 0
Mon Jan 18 15:16:20.902 Usb Host Notification Error Apple80211Set: Operation not supported seqNum 2528 en0
Mon Jan 18 15:16:20.927 <airport[399]> ERROR: rapportd (549) is not entitled for com.apple.wifi.join_history, will not allow request
<airport[399]> ERROR: sharingd (97542) is not entitled for com.apple.wifi.join_history, will not allow request
Mon Jan 18 15:16:51.114 Mon Jan 18 15:16:51.170 Usb Host Notification en0 driver available, seqNum 2529, Total 0```
````

Comment: What makes you suspect you were remotely hacked? The hacker would need not only correct login details, but also you would have had to have file sharing &/or remote login/management on.

Comment: Yes, that is the thing. I had all of those off (can we track), but when I checked yesterday the Bluetooth Sharing settings had "always accept" and save it automatically. And I would never do that. So I believe he changed that. And we were in a Apple Family group.

Comment: "I had all of those off" then it's unlikely anyone could get in. "but when I checked yesterday"… what?? If someone else could change those settings, they already had your computer in hand.

Comment: Additionally, we shared some app memberships, and there was one, SetApp, that you can download other paid apps for free And I believe he used one of the Apps, CleanShot, to monitor me, 2 days before the hack, but again, I am still learning about this and about what happened. So we had some things in common, that could have been exploited. I also saw this (added to story).

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear, but the person lives at my place, and yes, he could have changed my settings at any time, if get up to get water, or to get to the door.